# Estimating quantile correlations with rolling window

Tags: r, rolling-computation, quantile

I would like to estimate the quantile correlations between two variables, say **Y** and **X**, using the rolling window. I am using the R package `QCSIS` for this purpose. I tried to do the following

```
library(QCSIS)

#Generate some random variables
n   <- 4000
x   <- rnorm(n)
y   <- 2 * x + rt(n,df = 1)
tau <- 9 / 10
#calculate the static quantile correlation
fit<-qc(x = x, y = y, tau = tau)
fit$rho 
#calculate the rolling window quantile correlations
s<-260 #The window size

Rho.mat <- matrix(0,1,(n-s+1)) #create empty matrix to store the correlation coefficients
#running the loop
for(i in 1:(n-s+1)) {  
fit <- qc(x = x, y = y, tau = tau) 
Rho.mat[,i] <- fit$rho  

}
```

However, this code does not give the quantile correlation for each window and only repeats the static quantile correlation! Most of the other solutions I found online are related to linear regression and do not fit with the function I am using. That is why I am using a loop.

Comment: Inside the `for` you're running `fit <- qc(x = x, y = y, tau = tau)` each time. So it will return always the same value. Perhaps `fit <- qc(x = x[i:(i+s-1)], y = y[i:(i+s-1)], tau = tau)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use rollapplyr as follows to avoid loops:

```
library(zoo)
rollapplyr(cbind(x, y), s, function(z) qc(z[, 1], z[, 2], tau)$rho, 
  fill = NA, by.column = FALSE)
```

or over the indexes:

```
rollapplyr(seq_along(x), s, function(ix) qc(x[ix], y[ix], tau)$rho, fill = NA)
```

We can check the result like this:

```
library(zoo)
r.roll <- rollapplyr(cbind(x, y), s, function(z) qc(z[, 1], z[, 2], tau)$rho, 
  fill = NA, by.column = FALSE)

r.for <- x
for(i in seq_along(r.for)) {  
  r.for[i] <- if (i < s) NA else {
    ix <- seq(to = i, length = s)
    qc(x[ix], y[ix], tau = tau)$rho
  }
}

identical(r.roll, r.for)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Is there anyway to use the `rollapplyr` function with a forward expanding window instead of a fixed rolling window?

Comment: If x and y are each of length n then the width (2nd argument) can be a vector of length n such that ith element is the width at the ith iteration.  For example, 1:n  would use a widths of 1, 2, ..., n.   The width can also be a list which gives additional flexibility. See `?rollapply` for details.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I found that `rollapplyr` function gives more stable and better results than the for loop, even the results of `rollapplyr` are relatively robust for different window lengths, why are the results from the for loop so poor

Comment: Io get the same result.   See check that has been added at end of answer.